# PowerBI GROUPBY date AND identifier

Tags: group-by, powerbi, summarize

I am new to PowerBI and I am trying to group by the max date within the quarter, and then by unique identifier. Is this possible? My dataset looks like:

| Date | CompanyID | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/31/2018 | 1 | 100 |
| 3/31/2018 | 2 | 200 |
| 3/31/2018 | 3 | 100 |
| 6/30/2018 | 2 | 300 |
| 3/31/2018 | 4 | 100 |
| 2/28/2018 | 4 | 75 |
| 1/31/2018 | 4 | 50 |
| 6/30/2018 | 4 | 200 |

I'm hoping to get:

| Date | CompanyID | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/31/2018 | 1 | 100 |
| 3/31/2018 | 2 | 200 |
| 3/31/2018 | 3 | 100 |
| 3/31/2018 | 4 | 100 |
| 6/30/2018 | 2 | 300 |
| 6/30/2018 | 4 | 200 |

Appreciate any help here! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query (`Home=>Transform`)

- Add extra columns for Quarter and Year
- Group by ID / Quarter / Year
- Extract the maximum date from each subtable, along with the associated Sales number

```
let

//Change code in next line to reflect however you are reading in your data,
// or refer to the table you already have
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"CompanyID", Int64.Type}, {"Sales", Currency.Type}}),

//add custom columns for Quarter and Year
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Quarter", each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]),Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Year", each Date.Year([Date])),

//Group by ID / Quarter / Year
//Then return the last date for each subtable, and the corresponding Sales figure
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"CompanyID", "Quarter", "Year"}, {
        {"Date", each List.Max([Date]), type date},
        {"Sales", (t)=>Table.SelectRows(t, each [Date] = List.Max(t[Date]))[Sales]{0}, Currency.Type}
       }),

//Remove the Quarter and Year Column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Quarter", "Year"}),

//Set the desired order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Date", "CompanyID", "Sales"}),

//Sort by Date and Company ID Ascending
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{
        {"Date", Order.Ascending},
        {"CompanyID", Order.Ascending}
        })
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]